# PDF rendering is very slow

Tags: pdf, evince

I have a relatively fast machine (2.0GHz up to 2.8GHz AMD Quad-Core A10-4655M APU), running Xubuntu 15.10 (x64). Whenever I try to open large PDF files (>40MB), Evince takes quite a lot of time to render the pages (>4s). I tried other PDF viewers (e.g. Master PDF Editor), with more or less the same results.

Opening the very same PDF takes significantly less time in an old Windows 7 machine (Intel Core 2 DUO @ 2.93 GHz, 4GB RAM, no external GPU).

Is there something in the PDF rendering engine or engines (Poppler?) that makes opening and rendering PDF files considerably slower in Ubuntu than in Windows? Any ideas on how to reduce rendering time?

Comment: Using Chromium's built-in PDF viewer seems to be significantly faster than evince.

Comment: @Hitechcomputergeek Thanks. It does work faster than Evince.

Comment: Also might want to check out qpdfview - I've also heard mupdf suggested, but that seemed to handle a 900-page PDF poorly as well.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly this is a problem.

Adobe has pulled the plug on supporting its PDF reader app for Linux. This should come as no surprise, as the last time Adobe Reader for Linux was updated was in 2013.

Some alternatives do survive but they seem to be outdated or "slow" PDF web viewer's has been my way to view PDFs quickly however you can't edit on them.

[Here is a article](https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/792447-3-alternatives-to-the-adobe-pdf-reader-on-linux)